# delegated secure DDNS update in AD

Tags: dns, active-directory

For automation purposes, a script running on a Windows server needs to be able to securely update a record in AD-integrated DNS when a certain condition is triggered. 
This pertains an A record for an application, which is not the hostname of the Windows server on which the script runs.

The DNS entry has an ACL in the DNS zone to allow write by the service account running the script, and the GSS-TSIG DDNS update can easily be triggered from Linux/UNIX using a DNS client (eg. 'addns') that supports secure DDNS updates for arbitrary records in the DNS zone.

On Windows, I have had no luck so far finding any DNS client that supports GSS-TSIG (secure DDNS updates) for arbitrary records in DNS. All examples point to 'Register-DNSClient' or 'ipconfig /registerdns', which appear limited to registering the record for the local machine's hostname in the DNS zone.

Comment: Are you looking for something like https://github.com/Kevin-Robertson/Powermad/blob/master/Invoke-DNSUpdate.ps1 ?

Comment: @LisaJ - yes this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!